# Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060) Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

Estou tentando fazer uma conexão remota para o banco de dados Postgres, já instalei ele para fazer conexão remota mesmo, fui alterar os arquivos necessário e já estavam por padrão nas configurações corretas para acesso remoto, e mesmo com as informações corretas não consigo me conectar (ambas as máquinas estão na mesma rede).

```
import psycopg2

# dados
host = "192.168.*.**" //ipv4 da máquina onde o banco está, no banco coloquei o mesmo ip para o host
user = "postgres"
password = "projeto2022"
dbname = "postgres"
sslmode = "allow"

#string de conexão
conn_string = "host={0} user={1} dbname={2} password={3} sslmode={4}".format(host, user, dbname, password, sslmode)
conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

Já procurei em alguns tópicos da gringa mas não encontrei algo algo que me ajude com isso (pode ser que algo eu tenha entendido errado). Vi várias pessoas com o mesmo problema

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Algumas coisas que podem estar causado isso:

- Firewall? Verifica se a máquina que hospeda a base de dados aceita conexão de outras máquinas. Mesmo estando na mesma rede, esse tipo de configuração pode causar esse problema.
- Porta do Postgree. Por padrão, Postgree opera na porta 5432, então vale a pena conferir se o tráfego nessa porta tá aberto/liberado.
- Configuração do póprio Postgree. Mesmo você já tendo dito que conferiu, é bom salientar que a maioria dos sgbds, por padrão, vem configurados para recusarem conexões externas(de outros hosts)

Um outro teste simples pra identificar se uma máquina consegue alcançar a outra é usando ping do host que vai acessar para o host que hospeda o banco.

Comment: Era barragem do firewall mesmo, fui conferir e em ambas as máquinas a entrada de dados estava liberada, mas a saida estava bloqueada, configurei uma nova rule para a porta 5432 e agora ta indo certinho, obrigado!!

Comment: Fico feliz em ter ajudado :)